# I want to write a program that can remember where it stored a file

Tags: java

When I launch this program it will open a dialogue that asks the user to enter a location on his hard drive and then create a file. However, when the program is closed and reopen it, **it would have to open that file again.**

I am struggling with the bold part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to store the selected path somewhere.

When the user re-opens the application, check if there is a path stored, if yes, open that path, if not prompt the user again.

You can store it in a database, in a properties file or (i would suggest) store it in Java Preferences with the Java Preferences API ([Java Preferences API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/preferences/index.html))

So the flow would be:

1. **1st time open the application**
2. Prompt to select the file/path
3. Store it in Java preferences (for example)

---

1. **Re-opens the application**
2. Check if a file/path is stored
3. If yes, use that file/path
4. If no, prompt to select file/path
5. Store it in Java preferences (for example)

Answer (score 0):

- You should store the location of the file in any database or in a file
- You should read from database or from the file to get the file created by the user last time, when you start the application next time